# exe wont work, until i change the name, why?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple form application C#, with s simple form, running on XP (x86)
if i try to run it (by Double Click), all works on most computers,
on some computers the file wont run, 
if i change the name from "myApp.exe" to "myApp1.exe" then it runs.

i dont know why, cant find the logic
the same file in older version is running,
i know its not a code problem, because the process is not loading
(and i added a simple message box, it its not running)

i hope some one have an idea

thank your very much

Comment: How are you "running" it? Double click? Also, did you mean "myApp1.ext" or "myApp1.ex**e**"

Comment: Double click it, and i mean "myApp1.exe" (i fixed it, thanks)

Comment: Is there a config file in the same folder?

Comment: there is a config file, if i change the name of the file it is working

Comment: thank your jon, your tip gave me the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem,
it was the config file, it was an older version an needed an update,

thank you all

i still cant understand why the same file with a name change works...

Comment: It works because when there is no config file present, the application defaults to the assembly internal default values. The config is selected by name, and when you rename the app, it doens't find the config file anymore